# Store in a variable the result of a shell as Int

Tags: unix, haskell, ghc

So I work with files, and I need to know the largest line in file X. Using Unix *awk* results in a Int that I'm looking for. But in Haskell how can I return that value and save it to a variable?
I tried define something with `IO [Int] -> [Int]`

```
maxline = do{system "awk ' { if ( length > x ) { x = length } }END{ print x }' filename";}
```

doesn't work cause:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Int',against inferred type 'IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode'
```

Comment: +1 for your avatar and pseudonym. :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the [`system`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v%3asystem) action returns the exit status of the command you run which cannot be converted to `Int`. You should use the [`readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v%3areadProcess) to get the commands output.

```
> readProcess "date" [] []
  "Thu Feb  7 10:03:39 PST 2008\n"
```

Note that `readProcess` does not pass the command to the system shell: it runs it directly. The second parameter is where the command's arguments should go. So your example should be

```
readProcess "awk" [" { if ( length > x ) { x = length } }END{ print x }", "/home/basic/Desktop/li11112mp/textv"] ""
```

Comment: `*Prog> readProcess "awk ' { if ( length > x ) { x = length } }END{ print x }' /home/basic/Desktop/li11112mp/textv" [] []`
results
`(exit 127): failed`

Comment: Did you run the command directly from the shell and see what happens?

Comment: Perfect!! Works like a charm, i tried using the "" in different parts but never got the right spot...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v:readProcess) to get another program's output. You will not be able to convert the resulting `IO String` into a pure `String`; however, you can lift functions that expect `String`s into functions that expect `IO String`s. My two favorite references for mucking about with IO (and various other monads) are sigfpe's excellent blog posts, [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have.)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) and [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html).

For this particular problem, I would strongly suggest looking into finding a pure-Haskell solution (that is, not calling out to awk). You might like  [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:readFile), [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:lines), and [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy).